# Firefox 57 breaks most add-ons: Create new questions or keep using existing ones?

Tags: discussion

While [How to approach answers as software is updated](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339/how-to-approach-answers-as-software-is-updated) deals with this kind of topics, its first answer states "*It is extremely unusual for features to be removed in new version. This shouldn't be a big concern.*", which clearly does not apply to Firefox's update.

So, specifically for Firefox addon recommendation questions, should we:

- Create new questions for Firefox 57+?
- Keep using the existing questions?

Comment: The premise above is inaccurate.  Firefox 57 breaks *some* add-ons, and allows many new ones to work that would not before.  For factual information, see https://arewewebextensionsyet.com/

Comment: @RockPaperLizard: 70% of my addons do not work anymore. None of my addons have been made "to work that would not before".

Comment: In statistics, that's what we call an ***n of 1***.  A sample size of 1 is not useful... except for arriving at erroneous conclusions. ;)

Comment: BTW, my statement "allows many new ones to work that would not before" is a reference to the hundreds of Chrome extensions that have already been ported to Firefox, which was only feasible once WebExtensions was supported.

Answer (score 1):

As with other software where multiple versions are in active use, I don't see we'll need a special handling here. IMHO there are different groups of folks around in this context:

- those who upgraded to FF57 and never used any addons are not affected.
- those who upgraded to FF57 unaware and now suddenly find many of their addons broken will ask for "alternatives to X" anyway.
- those who, aware of the changes, did NOT upgrade, or switched to a fork like [Pale Moon](https://www.palemoon.org/) (remaining in the "old world" of XUL/XPCom without WE support) or Firefox ESR (currently at v52 feature-wise) will find those existing answers still useful
- those having switched to [Waterfox](https://www.waterfoxproject.org/downloads) or [Basilisk](http://www.basilisk-browser.org/) (compatible with both worlds, XUL/XPCom as well as WE) will find both types of answers helpful
- those who switched to an entirely different browser altogether ([Vivaldi](https://vivaldi.com/download/), [Otter-Browser](https://otter-browser.org/), [qutebrowser](https://qutebrowser.org/)) are not affected anyway either way

The only thing we should avoid is closing new questions clearly targeted at FF57+ as duplicates to those targeting older versions.

<sup>(Note that all alternative browsers/forks I've mentioned are cross-platform, so most Firefox users are covered)</sup>

Comment: LOL, you missed an entire category: "those who, aware of the changes, planned ahead and upgraded to FF57".

Comment: @RockPaperLizard Incidentally missed, as they are not affected – and covered by the last paragraph concerning "no-dupes".