# What's wrong with question like this?

Tags: discussion

[Freeware / cheap image editor software](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1049/freeware-image-editor-software)

I got 3 very hurried downvote. I've spent time to detail what I need, to avoid to make it too much opinionable. This software is called software reccomendation. I avoided the usage of any opinionable word.

**EDIT**
it's hard for me to explain why I fear an eccessive addiction to rules without explaining that addiction to rules in psychology is not a very good thing. I'm also trying to make people wonder why do they believe it's so important to avoid the word "list" and the word "best". And the possible impact on the final users of the website. Many are complaining..

Can you help me to improve this question suggesting modifics?

It seems it could be difficult for users to guess the mood of downloaded addicted people.

In my opinion this section should offer a service. Not try to impose the final users our convinction.

Have a look to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_psychology

> The approach focuses on the formation of what it believes to be faulty

Psychology deals on what we think is right or bad, true or false. But it's always totally strongly opinionable. This is what studious people says. I think many downvoted addicted people are discouraging users from posting for "window dressing" reasons. And that they should go deep in analyzing why they believe to be right.

In Psychology this kind of analysis (putting our own ideas / beliefs into discussion is called

> Socratic questioning (or Socratic maieutics)[1] is disciplined
>   questioning that can be used to pursue thought in many directions and
>   for many purposes, including: to explore complex ideas, to get to the
>   truth of things, to open up issues and problems, to uncover
>   assumptions, to analyze concepts, to distinguish what we know from
>   what we don't know, to follow out logical implications of thought or
>   to control the discussion.
>
> Two techniques commonly used to help identify irrational beliefs are
>   the downward arrow technique and the use of thought records to find
>   common themes. The downward arrow technique consists of challenging
>   statements people make about what they think is causing their negative
>   mood states by repeatedly asking the question, "If that were true, why
>   would it be so upsetting?" Thought records are a common form of
>   homework given to people in cognitive behavioural therapy that require
>   them to record their automatic thoughts associated with problem
>   situations (e.g., social avoidances or fears) during the week.
>
> Step 3: Challenge the irrational beliefs Once the irrational belief
>   underlying an automatic thought has been identified, it is important
>   to refute these beliefs by examining the evidence for them, and by
>   looking for alternative explanations.

**A short google translated explanation**

> **Socratic dialogue**
>
> The Socratic dialogue is a method of conducting the interview that
>   consists of a series of targeted questions and comments to guide the
>   patient to discover its dysfunctional beliefs and to promote him as a
>   critical attitude towards these.  Guided discovery or technique of
>   descending arrow
>
> **Guided discovery (through downward arrow)** is a method of conducting the interview is to ask the
>   patient gradually the meaning of his thoughts, in order to detect the
>   beliefs substates that he has about himself, about other people and
>   the world.

Comment: And could we leave out the psycobabble in meta posts please? I think we can leave it at "I felt the downvotes were unfair" rather than trying to confuse folks with a wall of text.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: I've tried to take authoritative fonts. Have also a look to Dichotomyc and http://www.anxieties.com/96/ocd-self#.UvyUTvldWGc (Ordering). Then ask you why is so important to avoid the word "best" and "list" while users will ALWAYS answer with one or a list of reccomended software.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: if you still think it's foundamental to avoid the word "list" and "best" we could improve the tooltip message.

Comment: People are going to miss what you're really trying to say. They may get annoyed. This may result in.. well, more downvotes. Leave off the psycology, focus on the problem and people are more likely to take well to what you're saying. I'm kinda annoyed myself, just not enough to point it out angrily. This is a comment about *this* question, rather than your use of the word list.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: it's hard for me to explain why I fear an eccessive addiction to rules without explaining that addiction to rules in psychology is not a very good things. I'm also trying to make people wonder why do they believe it's so important to avoid the word "list" and the word "best". And the possible impact on the final users of the website. Many are complaining..

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: I'm a very bad communicator, can you help me improving my question and pointing out the problems I've stated in my last comment?

Comment: Basically, you're overcomplicating your meta posts. You're posting a bunch of copy-pasted psycological writings that don't *really* have much to do with the real issues. I'm also confused since your questions on SO seem fine, and you're obviously not tripping over yourself there. Keep things simple, focus on your needs and problems, and keep in mind that you'll implicitly end up with a list, and select the best answer and you'll be fine. You're really overthinking it.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: ok, thanks, the problem I see is very simple: final user open one question using the word "list". People hurries to downvote becaouse they think the usage of this word is something bad. But actually it's just window dressing and the real problem could maybe be the opposite.. the real problem could be in the beliefs of the downvoting people. Psychology confirms that an excess of rule, and the excess of need for respect of rules is a very bad thing, and also states that is hard for people to recognize when they are exceeding.. the final result is that users get discouraged...

Answer (score 11):

I highly suspect your original topic played a big part on that:

> Can you make **a list** of freeware image editor software?

(emphasis mine). Additionally, the original post was formatted poorly.

Software lists have quite negative image here, as those will quickly degrade quality and usefulness of the site. Instead of software list, a good question can be answered with a single good solution (if such thing exists, which is obviously rarely the case). The goal should not be getting as many answers as possible ("a list of answers").

From [here](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/youre-doing-it-all-wrong):

> Let's keep in mind here that the name of the site is Software Recommendations, not Software Lists. That means you should be recommending software, not just going to Google, searching for something that matches, and posting a link to it [...]

Of course, your requirements are rather detailed and good, and overall, it's a good question, after it was edited.

Comment: @Ok.. but I can't ask for the best.. I can't ask for a list.. it's a bit fun :D. Exit SE, go back to reality. What should people REALLY answer to me? One or more programs.. the best or a list or some good.. it's just a matter of form of "window dressing". And if we are **really** concerned with this uninfluent things than the tooltip should say: "you can't use the word list / best and give a link to an example of window dressed question SE community people would like" otherwise users will become mad.. It's seems really excessive to me.. The maniacal need of rules is one of the DOC symptoms.

Comment: I kinda don't get your ranting - you wrote a post that was incorrectly formatted, and had a bad topic. Thus, it got plenty of downvotes. After it was edited by others, you got back to zero/positive, as it can be considered as high-quality. That's how SE sites work.

Comment: you say: "you wrote a post that was incorrectly formatted" psychology explains this is your belief. My belief is: "I wrote a normal question. People who are rules addicted started downvoting it without expanation and without asking themsef which was the pro of doing it. They were happy when the title went back into the rules". <br> Psychology also says: sympotms of OCD = 1. I must have certain things around me set in a specific order.
  2. I spend time making sure that things are in the right place.
   3. I notice when my things are out of place.

Comment: You're funny, IMHO.

Comment: You too for me.. I'm ranting because people don't make ANY effort to understand they are not always right. I've studied psichology, I've bought authorative sources but people just pretende he is right :D

Comment: @Sam without rules Stack exchange would become http://answers.yahoo.com/

Comment: @Sam - not to put too fine point on it, but if you don't like that the site has rules, you are welcome to use plethora of sites that do NOT. If you do not like specific rule, you need to convince people that that specific rule is bad. If you think a specific rule is OK but is mis-applied, you need to again convince people that they are mis-applying it on a specific question. Your post and comments read like the first of 3 options, the LEAST useful and constructive.

Comment: @Qwertie: with rules or without rules is seeing white and black. Have a look for dicothomic in psychology. It's a **strong** frequent mistaken belief. Check, it's not my opinion. It's science. World is grey not white&black. Seeing b&W is a kind of mental error. You can document here: http://translate.google.it/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=it&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mauroscardovelli.com%2FPNL%2FConsapevolezza_di_se%2FPensiero_dicotomico.html

Comment: @DVK: I'm just asking to make an effort to evaluate the rules and their appliance. I'm telling here there is some addiction to hurrie downvoting. It had originated in the last few months. I ask you to have a fast read about psicology's best practice. Very fast, and then ask deeply why you believe something is good or bad. Put yourself into discussion.

Comment: Really can't you see any addiction in an excess of downvoting, voting for dups and so on? We are closing very constructive and good questions. And for what? I've tried to document it in every way. People **believe** to work for the community. But I think they should ask themself: "why do I think this is good?". And discuss this idea again and again, and face the number of complaining people..

Comment: @Revious, Don't worry, this "hurried downvoting" problem definitely did not originate in the last few months. It has already been there as far back as 2011 (or even 2010)? If this is the first time you've seen this...... well, consider yourself lucky. You've not seen much my boy, I've seen many more: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/279911/24257

Answer (score 5):

Sam, thank you for the question, but we're trying to do something just a bit different here.

The "requirements" you listed in your question are ***so incredibly broad***, it is difficult to imagine that *most* free image editors don't already to do this. If you Google [free image editor](https://www.google.com/#q=free+image+editor) the top results return plenty of apps that do this. As a matter of fact, the top search results were already posted as "answers" because just about anything you find in that search essentially "answers" your question. But we don't want to turn this into a broad software listing service like a SoftPedia or something like download.com.

Please have a look at this post (below), particularly the section titled "The Ubiquity of Generalized Reviews":

[**Is this question acceptable?**](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248/how-to-deal-with-similar-but-not-duplicate-questions/254#254)

If you are looking for something more specific that any random search would not turn up, we'll be glad to help. If you can help us narrow down what you need, and tell us why any of the most popular image editor are not what you need, please feel free to update your post and try again. But I'm afraid this question is little more than "create me a giant list" of all-purpose image editors so we can pick through the collection later.

That's not really what we do here. Questions here are generally trying to solve a much much more specific problem. Your question is simply too broad to work on this site.

Comment: Sorry but I'm a bit upset, forgive my tone. In my humble opinion the real difference between Softpedia and this website is that here very serious people states the **best** software for doing something. Not that I should ask for software which are very rare.. Do you know Project Vega. It's a forensyc tool for image analyzing. Should users here ask just for that ultraspecific software? This is an acceptable question?

Comment: PickPick is one popular image editor. But it doens't stitch images together. I've specified very clearly that I don't need a software which supports filters. Do you know the difference between photo retouching and image editing? Ask people to improve their questions but closing without any knowledge of the domains seems very nonsense to me.

Comment: @sam Sorry about the confusion. It's not that the software you are requesting has to be terribly obscure, but you have to have a "problem statement" that actually needs solving. You're not saying that "I can't find software that does {x}", you're saying "let's create a list of very common software and vote which is 'best'" — essentially voting on its popularlity. That is very specifically ***not*** what we want this site to turn into. See http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/13031/laying-some-ground-rules-for-software-recommendations